# How to completely remove a dependency and its references with a Webpack plugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin

I am trying to write a Webpack plugin that finds and completely removes dependencies (anything imported with `require` or `import`) that follow a certain pattern.

Disclaimer, I know there is the [`IgnorePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/) but there are 2 reasons I am not using that:

1. I am not just removing the imports, I am memorizing what I have removed and will create a separate bundle with these dependencies
2. More importantly, I have tried to clone that plugin and memorize what I have deleted but that leads to errors. Let me explain

If I look [at the source code of the`IgnorePlugin`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/IgnorePlugin.js) it will remove them by returning null in the `beforeResolve` hooks. But that does not seem to signal Webpack to really ignore it, rather than to return a nullish reference. Because I am working inside [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) and that leads to an error where Next cannot find the references to the things I have removed.

So, this is my code:

```js
class NextCriticalWebpackPlugin {
  pluginName = this.constructor.name;
  requests = [];

  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.normalModuleFactory.tap(this.pluginName, factory => {
      factory.hooks.beforeResolve.tap(this.pluginName, result => this.checkIgnore(result));
    });
  }

  checkIgnore(result) {
    if (result && result.request && result.request.startsWith('next-critical/loader')) {
      this.requests.push(result.request);
      return null;
    }
    return result;
  }
}

module.exports = NextCriticalWebpackPlugin;
```

If I run Webpack, everything seems ok, but when I run my build, it will throw errors that it cannot find the modules that I had removed:

> `Cannot find module 'next-critical/loader!/Users/luke/Arbeit/Stroeer/Projekte/paper/apps/web/src/critrical/ads.ts'`

So I am wondering how I can tell Webpack to remove dependencies and its imports from the bundle.

Comment: Why not use dynamic method of next? It will split the import into a separate chunk and move all of its deps to it

Comment: I am implementing a NextPlugin that will follow the critical rendering path pattern and hoist critical CSS and JS into the `<head>`